# Exclude conditions in active relations, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

I am seeking a way to do the opposite of :

```
Model.where(:name => 'julian')
```

Something like :

```
Model.where(:name => is_not('julian'))
```

I have found this [post](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=22346). But, `find(:all, :conditions => {})` is now deprecated in rails 3 and moreover, I think a cleaner way to do this must exist.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure that `find(:all, :conditions => {})` is deprecated in rails 3?  I'm using 3.0.7 and don't get any deprecation warnings when i use it.

Comment: According to [this article](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface) passing `:conditions` to `find` as well as `find(:all)` is deprecated in Rails 3 and will be removed in Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
Model.where('models.name != ?', 'julian')
```

Unless, you want to get into building actual Arel conditions, in which case you would do something like:

```
Model.where(Model.arel_table[:name].not_eq('julian'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use meta_where gem: https://github.com/ernie/meta_where